# Subtract multiple columns based on condition in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset which looks like this. In my new dataset, I want to subtract the amount column(s) with remainder(s) column. For instance, if there is 5 **amount** column and 3 **remainder** column then the first amount column must be subtracted from the first remainder column, 2nd with 2nd and 3rd with 3rd. The last remaining 2 amount columns must be as it is.

```
amount1  amount2   amount3   amount4  amount5     remainder1  remainder2    remainder3  
 100      250       150        250       100         80         100          100 
 200      200       350        450       100        120         100          50
 300      150       450        200       100        150         100          100
 250      550       550        100       200         50         500          200
 550      200       650        250       200        500         100          500
```

My new dataset must look like this. Please note **am** stands for **amount** and **rem** stands for **remainder**.

```
 newamount1       newamount2         newamount3      newamount4     newamount5     
 20(am1-rem1)        150(am2-rem2)      50(am3-rem3)   amount4        amount5
 80                  100                300            amount4        amount5
 150                 50                 350            amount4        amount5
 200                 50                 350            amount4        amount5
 50                  100                100            amount4        amount4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R, you can use :

```
am_cols <- grep('Principal_', names(summary))

rm_cols <- grep('PrincipalPaid_', names(summary))

summary[is.na(summary)] <- 0

result <- cbind(summary[head(am_cols, length(rm_cols))] - summary[rm_cols], 
      summary[tail(am_cols, -length(rm_cols))])
names(result) <- paste0('new_principal', seq_along(result))
cbind(summary[1], result)

#  LoanId new_principal1 new_principal2 new_principal3 new_principal4
#1 825334           1965           2030           2051           2095
#2 825337           1965           2030           2051           2095
#3 838276           1961           2026           2047           2091
#4 850614              0           2275           2296           2346
#5 851791              0           2037           2059           2103
```

Comment: I tried above mentioned solution. I am getting an error which says **object of type 'closure' is not subsettable**. I have columns in the following format, **amount_Jan, amount_Feb** and so on. Similarly, **remainder_Jan, remainder_Feb** and so on

Comment: @RahulMishra What is the name of your dataframe? I have used `df` you need to change it based on the name of your dataframe. Can you share your actual data with `dput` the same way as in my answer?

Comment: Here is my dput  `structure(list(LoanId = c(825334, 825337, 838276, 850614, 851791
), Principal_NOV20 = c(1965, 1965, 1961, 2201, 1973), Principal_DEC20 = c(2030, 
2030, 2026, 2275, 2037), Principal_JAN21 = c(2051, 2051, 2047, 
2296, 2059), Principal_FEB21 = c(2095, 2095, 2091, 2346, 2103
), PrincipalPaid_NOV20 = c(NA, NA, NA, 2201, 1973), PrincipalPaid_DEC20 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), PrincipalPaid_JAN21 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, 5L
), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: I have used summary as my df name so I replaced df with summary. Also the principal-principalpaid is what I want as newprincipal.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I was wondering if there is any way to rename **new_principal1** with **new_principal_jan** and so on according to months, as I have to arrange my dataset monthwise.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using `tidyverse` could be the following.

Add row numbers to your data. Use `pivot_longer` to put your data into long format, and subtract `remainder` from `amount` for each month/row. Then put back into wide format.

Note this assumes instead of numbers at end of each column name, it ends with an underscore `_` and month abbreviation, as per comment.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c(".value", "month"), names_sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(newamount = amount - remainder) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = rn, names_from = month, values_from = newamount, names_prefix = "newamount_") %>%
  dplyr::select(-rn)
```

**Output**

```
  newamount_Jan newamount_Feb newamount_Mar newamount_Apr newamount_May
          <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1            20           150            50            NA            NA
2            80           100           300            NA            NA
3           150            50           350            NA            NA
4           200            50           350            NA            NA
5            50           100           150            NA            NA
```